# Generate all matrices given restrictions

Tags: python, matrix, integer, mathematical-optimization, combinatorics

I'm working on a multi-dimensional integer optimization problem, and at one step I have to run a function on all matrices of **dim = r x i** such that there is only one 1 per row and all the rest of the row is zeros.

I'm having a hard time writing the recursion code or loop for this, mainly because I need **r** to be a variable (**i** can be fixed no problem).

The main problem arising is that I would need r amount of for loops to execute this, so I believe a recursion function might be the way to go.

I know this code will execute in exponential time, but the size of the matrix won't be that large so it should be able to handle this brute-force solution.  (Usually r < 15, i < 5)

So, my question is how do I write an algorithm to generate all these matrices given the constraint?

Comment: And your question is ... ?

Comment: Excuse me if it seems stupid but I read there are a lot of zeros in the matrices and it takes a big amount of time. Did you use sparse matrices?